# my.cnfでserver-idが反映されない

Tags: mysql, mariadb

データベースのレプリケーション設定を行おうと思いまして、mariadbをインストールしました。
実際データベースの動作上は問題なく、マスタースレーブの設定も大体が上手くいきました。
最終の段階で`show slave status`を打つと下記のようになりました。

```
Slave_IO_Running: No
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Last_IO_Errno: 1593
```

何がおかしいのかID系を調べたところ`select uuid();`は問題なかったのですが、
`show variables like '%server%';`の結果がマスタースレーブ共に`server_id=1`でした。
`my.cnf`自体には`server-id=102`と記載があったのにもかかわらず反映されていないようです。

ちなみに`set global server_id=102;`と打って手動で変更するとレプリケーションも通りました。
`/datadir/mysql/auto.cnf`も疑いましたが、そもそも存在しませんでした。
`log-bin=mysql-bin`の値はレプリケーションのステータスから反映されているので
`my.cnf`が読めていないわけではなさそうなのですが……
ファイルの場所自体は`/etc/my.cnf`で、他のユーザディレクトリなどの場所には存在しませんでした。

なにか原因になりそうな箇所が分かりませんでしょうか？
以上、どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

環境
`mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.52-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`
`CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`

Comment: お使いのOSはなんでしょうか。

Comment: インストールしているOS情報を追記いたしました。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが`/etc/my.cnf.d`の下に設定ファイルはありませんか？

Comment: `my.cnf`ばかり頭にあって`find`してましたが`/etc/my.cnf.d/server.cnf`内に`server-id`の記述がございました。。。変更してDBを再起動でIDの変更を確認いたしました。ありがとうございます。改めて回答を頂けないでしょうか？

Comment: おお、よかったですね。改めて回答に書きました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS7 では `/etc/my.cnf.d` の下に設定ファイルが作成され `/etc/my.cnf` 内でインクルードされますのでそちらも探してみてください。

```
/etc/my.cnf

#
# include all files from the config directory
#
!includedir /etc/my.cnf.d
```